# How to create multi-colored shape background in Android activity

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I am looking to make my `Activity`'s background into two colors. A custom color on top and a white color on the bottom. The thing is I don't want to separate them with a horizontal line. I would like to create something very similar to the image provided. I really wouldn't know where to start to create this...

[image]

I tried this, but again, I don't really want to have a horizontal separation. I would prefer a separation more like the image.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FAFAFA" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="300dp" android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I think you may have better luck using Vector Drawables..  
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html

What i've done in the past was create an svg image and just convert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this as a background of your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:pathData="M0,0 L0,50 L500,80 L500,0 z" />
</vector>
```

This looks like this in my emulator.

[image]